# Is the annual system still in vogue anywhere in Europe, North America, Australia, or East Asia? And what about the 2-year B.A. / B.Sc. degree?

Tags: undergraduate-education, exams, assessment

In Pakistan, we have until now had 2-year B.A./B.Sc. and 2-year M.A./M.Sc. university degrees after our 12th grade F.A./F.Sc. qualifications. Thus the former was a 14-year academic qualification, whereas the latter was the 16-year qualification. In these degrees, the assessment was based on either end-of-degree aggregate examinations of all the subjects taught or at most annual examinations. This was the system introduced in the subcontinent by the British government.

I'm wondering if this kind of system still exists in the UK today, or in other countries of Western / Northern Europe, North America, Australia, Singapore, Hong Kong, China, or Japan.

And have all the above-mentioned countries completely switched to a semester/trimester/quarter-based system of continuous assessment? Or, does the annual system still exists anywhere?

Finally, in Pakistan, universities would often send their papers to teachers of other universities for checking / grading in order to ensure transparency / accountability, but later on only papers of the affiliated colleges were sent to the respective academic departments of their affiliating university. Is this practice still in vogue anywhere else as well?

Comment: I may be misunderstand, but isn't this how the Tripos system at Cambridge works?